# How to remove SIGABRT error in my C++ code

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search

My task was to find if a path exist from source to destination in a given graph(adjacency matrix). The source is 1 and the destination is 2 and the path can travel only through number 3 in the matrix. I have used BFS to solve this problem but I am getting SIGABRT error. If anyone could please help me, I am still a beginner in coding. I have attached the code here.
The question is as follows Given a N X N matrix (M) filled with 1, 0, 2, 3. The task is to find whether there is a path possible from source to the destination while traversing through blank cells only. You can traverse up, down, right, and left.

A value of cell 1 means Source.
A value of cell 2 means Destination.
A value of cell 3 means Blank cell.
A value of cell 0 means Blank Wall.
Note: there are only a single source and a single destination.
The first line of input is an integer T denoting the no of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case consists of 2 lines. The first line of each test case contains an integer N denoting the size of the square matrix. Then in the next line are N*N space-separated values of the matrix (M).

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

bool inside(int first, int second,int r)
{
    if(first<r && second<r && first>=0 && second>=0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int isPath(pair <int, int> source, pair <int,int> dest, vector <vector<int>> &adj, vector <vector <bool>> &visit, int r)
{
    queue <pair<int,int>> q;
    q.push(source);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        pair <int, int> curr = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(inside(curr.first,curr.second,r) && !visit[curr.first][curr.second] && adj[curr.first][curr.second]==2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if(inside(curr.first+1,curr.second,r) && (adj[curr.first+1][curr.second]==3||adj[curr.first+1][curr.second]==2) && !visit[curr.first+1][curr.second])
        {
            curr.first++;
            q.push(curr);
            visit[curr.first][curr.second]=true;
            curr.first--;
        }
        if(inside(curr.first-1,curr.second,r) && (adj[curr.first-1][curr.second]==3||adj[curr.first-1][curr.second]==2) && !visit[curr.first-1][curr.second])
        {
            curr.first--;
            q.push(curr);
            visit[curr.first][curr.second]=true;
            curr.first++;
        }
        if(inside(curr.first,curr.second+1,r) && (adj[curr.first][curr.second+1]==3||adj[curr.first][curr.second+1]==2) && !visit[curr.first][curr.second+1])
        {
            curr.second++;
            q.push(curr);
            visit[curr.first][curr.second]=true;
            curr.second--;
        }
        if(inside(curr.first,curr.second-1,r) && (adj[curr.first][curr.second-1]==3||adj[curr.first][curr.second-1]==2) && !visit[curr.first][curr.second-1])
        {
            curr.second--;
            q.push(curr);
            visit[curr.first][curr.second]=true;
            curr.second++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int r,c,t,i,j;
    vector <vector <int>> adj(r, vector <int>(c));
    vector <vector <bool>> visit(r, vector <bool>(c));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            visit[i][j]=false;
        }
    }
    cin>>t;
    int p=t;
    vector <int> store(t);
    pair <int,int> source;
    pair <int,int> dest;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>r;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<r;j++)
            {
                cin>>adj[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<r;j++)
            {
                if(adj[i][j]==1)
                {
                    source.first=i;
                    source.second=j;
                }
                if(adj[i][j]==2)
                {
                    dest.first=i;
                    dest.second=j;  
                }
            }
        }
        int k=0, max=0;
        store[t-1]=isPath(source, dest, adj, visit,r);
    }
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        cout<<store[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int r,c,t,i,j;
vector <vector <int>> adj(r, vector <int>(c));
vector <vector <bool>> visit(r, vector <bool>(c));
```

You use `r` and `c` before you initialize them. You should first read values, then initialize the vectors. For example:

```
int r,c,t,i,j;
// Declare vectors but don't initialize yet
vector <vector <int>> adj;
vector <vector <bool>> visit;

// Later
cin >> r;
cin >> c;

adj = vector <vector <int>>(r, vector <int>(c));
visit = vector <vector <bool>>(r, vector <bool>(c));
```

You are using `r` and `r` as `for` loop limits when you go through the vectors. Did you mean `r` and `c`?

Comment: Silly me, I corrected my mistake. Thank you. But still, my code is running for a small matrix but again throwing SIGABRT error in case of a larger square matrix. If you could please help me if there is some logical error.

Comment: @AnkeshKumarSingh https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `r` and `c`. In this case `r` and `c` can be very big.

Comment: I don't understand, what does it mean by using init. If you could please clarify it, it would be helpful. My code is running for small matrix but again throwing SIGABRT error in case of larger square matrix.